# Boolean and String Values in the same table

Tags: mysql, database-design, data-modeling

I'm designing my first good sized project and I want to be sure I'm on the right path here so I thought I would run it by the community.

I have vendors that submit products to companies. The vendors choose which company they want to submit to and that brings up a page of questions chosen by the company. So far I have a Table of companies, a table of vendors, and table of products. Each with their own primary key, easy enough. My issue is with my table called submissions that starts to tie them all together for each new submission. I am trying to get away from having a submission table with a thousand columns because the companies all want to ask different questions. If I have

```
Table Submissions
  submission_id
  date
  product_id FK
  vendor_id FK
  company_id FK

and 

Table Questions
  question_id
  question

and to bridge the many to many

Table Questions_Submissions
  questions_submissions_id
  submission_id  FK
  question_id  FK
  answer
```

Would this be the recommended path for normalization and if so is there any harm having the column answer contain boolean and string results or should I somehow break the boolean questions into another table? I'm expecting millions of rows of data over the next few years and want to be sure I dont design this wrong from the beginning. Thanks for any feedback if you see a glaring error or red flag in this design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So far I have a Table of companies, a table of vendors, and table of products. Each with their own primary key, easy enough.

Each row has its own id number. That's not quite the same thing as you'd get by normalizing a relation. In a relational database, the important thing is not identifying a row, it's identifying what the row represents.

So, for example, this table

```
Table Questions
  question_id
  question
```

could quite easily end up with data that looks like this.

```
question_id  question
--
1            What is your name?
2            What is your name?
3            What is your name?
4            What is your name?
5            What is your name?
```

Each row is uniquely identified, but each question (the important thing) is not.  You need a unique constraint on {question}.

> I have vendors that submit products to companies.

```
Table Submissions
  submission_id
  date
  product_id FK
  vendor_id FK
  company_id FK
```

You need a unique constraint on either {product_id, vendor_id, company_id} or {date, product_id, vendor_id, company_id}.

You also need a table of vendor products. Your table allows a vendor to submit any product--including every product they don't sell--to a company.

> The vendors choose which company they want to submit to and that brings up *a page of questions chosen by the company*. (Emphasis added)

Nothing in your schema stores the questions a company has chosen.

> is there any harm having the column answer contain boolean and string results

You can express just about any common data type as a string. But with this structure, you can't constrain boolean values to just two values. If you add the possibility of numeric results, you can't constrain them to sane values, either.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. Exactly the type of response I was hoping the community could provide.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly one way to go about it, and it looks pretty good.

You can do some clever things with the answer and some if statements in the query to handle the different types of answers, but it does add some complexity to the solution, so you should think about what you are trying to do with the answers.

For Boolean, you can just as easily get away with "true" or "false" in the varchar field, and do a count on them.  If you needed to get answers that are numeric or dates, for sums or averages directly in the query, you could split the answer into types.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I wasn't sure if the space that a boolean would take up vs a string should be a consideration. Disc space is cheap so if its not considered a big deal I would rather go true/false, yes/no to avoid some lines of code for conversion later.